# What is adjoint of integral operator $S$?

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

I would like to find  the adjoint of parametrized integral operator  with respect to $L^2$ norm
\begin{align}
&S: L^2[0,2\pi] \to L^2[0,2\pi]\\
&(S\varphi)(t)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \Phi(p(t),z(\tau))\varphi(\tau)|z'(\tau)|d\tau
\end{align}
where $z(t):=(z_1(t),z_2(t)), t\in [0,2\pi]$ and $p(\tau):=(p_1(\tau),p_2(t)), \tau\in [0,2\pi]$,

also $\Phi(p(t),z(\tau))=K_0(|(p(t)-z(\tau)|)$ which is modified bessel function and it is real

By using $<S\varphi, \psi>=<\varphi,S^*\psi>$,
the obtained adjoint of $S$ equals
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \Phi(z(t),p(\tau))\psi(\tau)|p'(t)|dt
\end{align}

Is this result true ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\langle S\varphi,\psi \rangle&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\psi(t)\Phi(p(t),z(\tau))\varphi(\tau)|z'(\tau)|\,\mathrm{d}\tau\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\psi(\tau)\Phi(p(\tau),z(t))\varphi(t)|z'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}\tau\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\langle \varphi,S^*\psi\rangle,
\end{align}
with $$S^*\psi(t)=\int_0^{2\pi}\Phi(p(\tau),z(t))\psi(\tau)|z'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}\tau.$$
Of course, this is the long way by interchanging the integrating variables. One could just recognize that Hilbert-Schmidt operators of the form
$$
\varphi \mapsto \int_a^bK(x,y)\varphi(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
have adjoint
$$
\psi\mapsto \int_a^b \overline{K(y,x)}\psi(y)\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$
In this case, it appears everything is real, so conjugates are irrelevant.

Comment: $S^*\psi(t)=\int_0^{2\pi}\Phi(p(\tau),z(t))\psi(\tau)|z'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}\tau.$   Is $|z'(\tau)|=|p'(\tau)|$ in the integral ?